# sujet implicite lors de répétitions

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels

J'ai tendance à mettre en évidence les sujets lorsqu'il y a répétition immédiate (c'est-à-dire à *supprimer* ces répétitions) dans mes phrases. Par exemple:

> J'ai pris connaissance de ce document et ai rédigé une note ...

S'agit-il d'une pratique correcte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Oui](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4133), et il s'agit d'une pratique courante. On peut juste reprocher à la phrase donnée en exemple la suite *et ai* qui n'est pas forcément très heureuse.

On peut facilement l'éviter en omettant aussi [l'auxiliaire](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4134) :

> J'ai pris connaissance de ce document et rédigé une note

Comment: Merci. Oui, en effet, je n'ai pas réfléchi à cet exemple très longtemps. Cela dit, avec mon accent, "et ai" se prononce [eɛ], ce qui, à mes oreilles, n'est pas si déroutant.

Comment: ____ hé, hé ;-)